# Get selected portion of image in picturebox in another picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a picturebox with image, in which I have drawn a rectangular selection. I want to get the selected portion of image in another picturebox. How can I get that? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the `rect` is the `Rectangle` which you passed in the `Graphics.DrawRectangle` is calculated in your the coordinates of your `pictureBox`. You can use `RectangleToScreen` and `RectangleToClient` to get that portion in another `pictureBox` like this:

```
Rectangle portion = pictureBox2.RectagleToClient(pictureBox1.RectangleToScreen(rect));
//portion is the Rectangle calculated in the coordinates of pictureBox2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use coordinates of the selection to create `Rectangle rectangle` then:

```
   Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBoxImage);
   Bitmap croppedBitmap = sourceBitmap.Clone(rectangle, sourceBitmap.PixelFormat);
```

after that you may use `croppedBitmap` in another picturebox. Don't forget to dispose unused images. That's all.